# Cauchy Sequence

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

In $C[0, 1]$, show that $\{f_n\}$, where $f_n(x) = 
\frac{nx}{n+x}, x \in [0,1]$, is a Cauchy sequence.

I know the definition that a sequence is Cauchy sequence, if there exists a non negative number $m_{°}$ such that $d(x_{n},x_{m})<\epsilon$ for all $n,m\ge m_{°}$.

What kind of elements am I supposed to choose from the sequence to show whether the sequence is Cauchy or not?

Comment: What is the metric of $C[0,1]$?

Comment: Once you know the metric, write $d(f_n,f_m)$ using that knowledge.  You need a good estimate of that from above for a proof of $d(f_{n},f_{m})<\epsilon$.

Comment: The metric is not given in the question but I will assume that the metric will be $d(x,y)=sup_{t \in [a,b]}|x(t)-y(t)|$

Comment: If the sequence is covergent in this metric, it must be Cauchy. The converse also happens to be true for this metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that we are using the supremum metric.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$.

Then note that for all $t \in [0,1]$ and $n>m>N$,
$$|f_n(t)-f_m(t)|=|\frac{nt}{n+t}-\frac{mt}{m+t}|=t^2|\frac{n-m}{(n+t)(m+t)}|\leq \frac{n-m}{nm}< \frac{1}{m}<\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$$
Taking supremum on both sides we get that
$$d(f_n,f_m)<\epsilon$$
As we wanted to show.